# how to create a gridview with spaces in specified columns

Tags: java, android, gridview

I am trying to create a `gridview` like given in image but I'm not able to do it, I don't know how to give spaces between specified columns. I'm trying to develop a simple bus seat booking app. Please help

EDIT:-  should i use different drawable selector image for these seat selection??

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="290dp"
        android:layout_height="390dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp">

        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/grid"
            android:layout_width="170dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:columnWidth="60dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:numColumns="2"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth" />
        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/grid2"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:gravity="center">

        </GridView>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image]

Comment: share your code here

Comment: Try right margin on the left elements.

Comment: share your gridItem layout and gridview adapter code

Comment: I have created only design code, i want to make items clickable for that i haven't code in java... I have updated my question